# Пустые переменные в общей строке PHP

Tags: php, robokassa

Получаю переменные из формы. (Они 100% поступают, проверял).
После этого заношу их все в одну переменную:

```
$crc  = "$mrh_login:$out_summ:$inv_id:$mrh_pass1:Shp_date=$shp_date:Shp_email=$shp_email:Shp_name=$shp_name:Shp_surname=$shp_surname:Shp_time=$shp_time";
```

Через знак ":". Когда смотрю эту строку при передаче, то значения переменных пустые!

Я не знаю как иначе описать эту проблему. Если задать эти переменные вручную, не считывая их из формы, то они есть. Но я точно проверил, что переменные до этой строки не пустые, в них точно есть значения.
Не знаю, почему переменные передаются в эту строку пустыми. Пожалуйста, выручите. Всю голову себе на этом сломал.

Весь код:

```
$mrh_login = "dimapupkin";
$mrh_pass1 = "mypass231";
$shp_name = urlencode(strip_tags(trim($_POST['Shp_name'])));
$shp_surname = urlencode(strip_tags(trim($_POST['Shp_surname'])));
$shp_email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['Shp_email']));
$shp_date = $_POST['Shp_date'];
$shp_time = $_POST['Shp_time'];

$crc  = "$mrh_login:$out_summ:$inv_id:$mrh_pass1:Shp_date=$shp_date:Shp_email=$shp_email:Shp_name=$shp_name:Shp_surname=$shp_surname:Shp_time=$shp_time";
```

Вывод:
     `dimapupkin:20:0:mypass231:Shp_date=:Shp_email=:Shp_name=:Shp_surname=:Shp_time=`

Comment: Ты видимо забыл добавить name="" в форме, хотя написал что данные приходят

Comment: Да нет, добавил

Answer (score 5):

Не понимаю что ты не так сделал, но у меня всё приходит, вот держи пример:

```
<body>
    <form action="/form.php" method="post">
        <label>Имя</label>
        <input type="text" name="Shp_name"><br>
        <label>Фамилия</label>
        <input type="text" name="Shp_surname"><br>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="Shp_email"><br>
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="Shp_date"><br>
        <label>Time</label>
        <input type="text" name="Shp_time"><br>
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Отправляем данные на form.php:

```
$mrh_login = "dimapupkin";
$mrh_pass1 = "mypass231";
$shp_name = urlencode(strip_tags(trim($_POST['Shp_name'])));
$shp_surname = urlencode(strip_tags(trim($_POST['Shp_surname'])));
$shp_email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['Shp_email']));
$shp_date = $_POST['Shp_date'];
$shp_time = $_POST['Shp_time'];

echo $crc  = "$mrh_login:$out_summ:$inv_id:$mrh_pass1:Shp_date=$shp_date:Shp_email=$shp_email:Shp_name=$shp_name:Shp_surname=$shp_surname:Shp_time=$shp_time";
```

Вот получился результат:

```
dimapupkin:::mypass231:Shp_date=кек1:Shp_email=1кек:Shp_name=Kek:Shp_surname=lolkek:Shp_time=1kek1
```

Comment: Вот и я о том же. Не вижу в чём проблема, но она есть

Comment: @Владислав.С примени код, будет работать, проверено